# jQuery widget factory access options and method in public method in setInterval

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have created some widget factory and i want to access it's options or method in public method, but it return error "142 Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method" or "cannot read property". How to access it correctly?

Here is the example:

```
function($){
  $.widget("demo.myWidget",{ 
    options:{
      myVar:0
    },
    _create:function(){
      //this line work in here
      alert(this.options.myVar);
    },
    calledFunction : function(){
      alert(this._getVar());
    },
    pubFunction : function(){
      setInterval(this.calledFunction, 1000);
    },
    _getVar : function(){
      return this.options.myVar;
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("selector").myWidget();
   $("selector").myWidget("pubFunction");
});
```

If I access the options in the _create method it's work fine. Thank you before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code is fine, but you have syntax errors near the end of the anonymous function. The call to `$.widget()` does not end properly, and the anonymous function itself is never called.

Try:

```
(function($) {
  $.widget("demo.myWidget", { 
    options: {
      myVar:0
    },
    _create: function() {
      //this line work in here
      alert(this.options.myVar);
    },
    calledFunction: function() {
      alert(this._getVar());
    },
    pubFunction: function() {
      this.setInterval(this.calledFunction, 1000);
    },
    _getVar : function() {
      return this.options.myVar;
    }
  });        // <-- End call to $.widget().
})(jQuery);  // <-- End anonymous function and call it with the jQuery object.
```

Once this is done, the code works as expected. You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE88y/).

**EDIT:** Concerning the issue described in your comment, that's because when [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) invokes your callback function, `this` is bound to the global object (`window` in our case), not to your object. You can work around that problem with [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
pubFunction : function() {
  setInterval($.proxy(this.calledFunction, this), 1000);
},
```

Comment: oops, forgot to add the end call. but still not working if i access options after setInterval. thank you for reminding.

Comment: There is indeed an additional issue with `setInterval()`. See my updated answer.